# Hash table(linear probing)

Tags: c++

I am making a hash table using linear probing and i have to resize the array when ever the load factor i.e (no. of elements entered in hashtable)/(size of hashtable), becomes greater than 0.5, i have to resize the array.I am doing the resizing by initializing a pointer in a class which contains functions related to hashtable.I am putting the pointer equal to an array of a struct (struct only contains a string) of size 100.every time load factor becomes greater than 0.5, i resize the array by making a new array of double the previous size and point the pointer to the new array.I also have an int which stores current size of array and which is updated with every instance in which resize function is used.The number of elements inserted are incremented with every call to insert function.Am I doing this correctly?Below is my code

```
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int power(int a,int b)
{
   for (int i=0;i<b;i++)
   {
       a*=a;
   }
   return a;
};

struct Bucket
{
    string word;
};   

const int size=100;

class LProbing
{
  private:
          int a; //a constant which is used in hashing
          int cursize;  //current size of hash table
          Bucket *Table;  //pointer to array of struct
          int loadfactor; //ratio of number of elements entered over size of hashtable
          int n;  //number of elements entered
          Bucket table[size];   //array of structs
  public:
          LProbing(int A);  //constant is decided by user 
          void resize();
          void insert(string word);
          void Lookup(string word);
};

LProbing::LProbing(int A)
{  
   cursize=size;                   
   a=A;
   Table=table;
   loadfactor=0;  //initially loadfactor is 0 as number of elements entered are 0
   n=0;
}

void LProbing::resize() 
{
    cout<<"resize"<<endl;
    loadfactor=n/cursize;   //ensuring if resize needs to be done
    if (loadfactor<=0.5)
    {
       return;
    }                                      
    const int s=2*cursize;  
    Bucket PTable[s];
    for (int i=0;i<cursize;i++)
    {
        if (Table[i].word.empty())
        continue;

        //rehashing the word onto the new array
        string w=Table[i].word;    
        int key=0;
        for (int j=0;j<w.size();j++)
        {
           unsigned char b=(unsigned char)w[j];
           key+=(int)power(a,i)*b;
        }
        key=key%(2*cursize);
        PTable[key].word=w;  //entering the word in the new array
    }
    Table=PTable;  //putting pointer equal to new array
    cursize=2*cursize;  //doubling the current size of array
}

void LProbing::insert(string word)
{
   cout<<"1"<<endl; 
   n++;  //incrementing the number of elements entered with every call to insert

    //if loadfactor is greater than 0.5, resize array
   loadfactor=n/cursize;
   if (loadfactor>0.5)
   {               
       resize();
    }                
   //hashing the word
   int k=0;
   for (int i=0;i<word.size();i++)
   {
       unsigned char b=(unsigned char)word[i];
       int c=(int)((power(a,i))*b);
       k+=c;
       cout<<c<<endl;
   }

   int key=0;
   key=k%cursize;
   cout<<key<<endl;
   //if the respective key index is empty enter the word in that slot
   if (Table[key].word.empty()==1)
   {
       cout<<"initial empty slot"<<endl;
       Table[key].word=word;
   }
   else  //otherwise enter in the next slot
   {
       //searching array for empty slot
       while (Table[key].word.empty()==0)
       {
        k++;
        key=k%cursize;
       }
       //when empty slot found,entering the word in that bucket
       Table[key].word=word;
       cout<<"word entered"<<endl;
   }
}             

#include "Linear Probing.cpp"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   LProbing H(35);
   ifstream fin;
   fin.open("dict.txt");
   vector<string> D;

   string d;
   while (getline(fin,d))
   {
       if (!d.empty())
       {
           D.push_back(d);
       }
   }
   fin.close();
   for (int i=0;i<D.size();i++)
   {
       H.insert(D[i]);
   }
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: To convince yourself that it's working (or not), construct a suite of unit tests.

Comment: When i am running this code on a file of words, i sometimes get negative values of key.i don't understand why that happens because i am not subtracting anything and i convert every letter to unsigned char first before calculating it's value.

Comment: as a result of negative key, the program gives an error.

Answer (score 3):

You may find it helpful somewhere:
http://www.cs.rmit.edu.au/online/blackboard/chapter/05/documents/contribute/chapter/05/linear-probing.html

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with big numbers and variable "key" is overflowing in:

```
key += (int)power(a,i)*b
```

Comment: I am giving a positive input.i'll attach the main file

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say??

Comment: I just want a random value for a so its okay if i give any value to it.

Comment: Yeah I just displayed the values of key and thats exactly whats happening.but now the program gets stuck immediately after the array is resized

Comment: I don't have enough reputation.just a newbie.

Comment: you can use long long instead of int

Comment: I am getting negative values of key.why do you think is that?is it because of overflowing?but how can that be when I am using long long?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like loadfactor is calculated as `int/int` so it will stay 0 until it reaches 1. Try casting the inputs to the division into floats.